# Filling a tree using random values using loop

Tags: c

I have the following question:

I created this structure:

```
typedef struct Tree{
    float pnt[2];
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
}Node;
```

My goal is to establish the initial tree with random points (each point of dim=2). We can do that manually from the main function something like this:

```
Node n[] = {
    {{2, 3}}, {{5, 4}}, {{9, 6}}, {{4, 7}}, {{8, 1}}, {{7, 2}}
};
```

However, I want to do that using a loop that fills each node with random point. Is it correct to do the following:

```
Node n;
int num_nodes = 6;

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < num_nodes; ++i) {
    n->pnt = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite - since `node` is an array, and `pnt` is an array of two points within each struct, you would need to do something like this:

```
const int num_nodes = 6;
Node n[num_nodes];

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < num_nodes; ++i) {
    n[i].pnt[0] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    n[i].pnt[1] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul .. Well explained :)